# Is Ajanu (At / Below the Knees) Arms From Birth or can they be developed over time

Tags: scripture, upanishads, avatars, yoga, spirituality

We all know that the human body is temporary and changes over time (infant --> child --> adolescence --> adult ---> old ---> cadaver). We also know that practicing spirituality can change people with time (give people 8 shidhis). One sign of divinity are long (ajanu) arms. Some people are born with ajhanu arms (like Lord Rama and Lord Krishna), but if someone is not born with ajanu arms, can their arms become ajanu if they practice yoga (karma, jana, bhakti...), spirituality over time? Are there any mentions in the scriptures that say ajanu arms can only happen at birth?